# Create a file, define its type and path

Tags: java

I want to make a program that **creates a file** and the user **defines its type** (txt, Html,....) and also **its path**. I've tried it with jfilechooser but I can't do it. Is there an easy way to do this?

What I've done so far is to define a path and create a folder there but that's not what I want to do.

Here's my code (a piece of it):

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setDialogTitle("choose a file");
int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File folder = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filepath = folder.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("The path of the selected file is " + filepath);

    File f = null;
    boolean bool = false;

    try {      
       f = new File(folder.getPath());           
       bool = f.mkdirs();

       System.out.print("Directory created? " + bool);
    } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the worst code formatting I've ever seen. Hope you don't mind my editing the crap out of it.

Comment: What does *"but i can't do it"* mean? --- Why do you call the variable `folder` when it contains the *file* path? --- What's the point of `new File(folder.getPath())` when `folder` is already a `File` with that path?